# define which editorFor is used

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a application in which employees can select which days they are present and which days they are not. Also if they are present; at what times. I am using the `kendo ui` with the `kendoTimePicker()` to select the times.

I am working on a function which disables the corrosponding timePicker if absent is selected in the `editorFor`. Say the user isn't working on Fridays, the user then selects absent in the menu and the `jQuery` script disables the `startVr` and `endVr` timePickers.

Currently (reffering to my script) it does not matter in which `editorFor` you select "absent"; the `startMa` and `endMa` timePickers are disabled.

**Now on to my question:**

How do I let the script know that the end-user sets the monday `editorFor` on absent and not one of the others?

this is what I currently have:

jQuery:

```
$('#startMa, #startDi, #startWo, #startDo, #startVr, #startZa, #startZo').kendoTimePicker({
    format: "HH:mm",
    min: "8:00",
    max: "17:30",
    value: "8:30",
    interval: 15
});

$('#endMa, #endDi, #endWo, #endDo, #endVr, #endZa, #endZo').kendoTimePicker({
    format: "HH:mm",
    min: "8:00",
    max: "17:30",
    value: "17:00",
    interval: 15
});

$('#maandag, #dinsdag, #woensdag, #donderdag, #vrijdag, #zaterdag, #zondag').change(function () {
    var maStartTimePicker = $('#startMa').data("kendoTimePicker");
    var maEndTimePicker = $('#endMa').data("kendoTimePicker");

    var diStartTimePicker = $('#startDi').data("kendoTimePicker");
    var diEndTimePicker = $('#endDi').data("kendoTimePicker");

    var woStartTimePicker = $('#startWo').data("kendoTimePicker");
    var woEndTimePicker = $('#endWo').data("kendoTimePicker");

    var doStartTimePicker = $('#startDo').data("kendoTimePicker");
    var doEndTimePicker = $('#endDo').data("kendoTimePicker");

    var vrStartTimePicker = $('#startVr').data("kendoTimePicker");
    var vrEndTimePicker = $('#endVr').data("kendoTimePicker");

    var zaStartTimePicker = $('#startZa').data("kendoTimePicker");
    var zaEndTimePicker = $('#endZa').data("kendoTimePicker");

    var zoStartTimePicker = $('#startZo').data("kendoTimePicker");
    var zoEndTimePicker = $('#endZo').data("kendoTimePicker");

    if (this.value == "false" || this.value == "afwezig") {
        maStartTimePicker.enable(false);
        maEndTimePicker.enable(false);
    } else{
        maStartTimePicker.enable(true);
        maEndTimePicker.enable(true);
    }
});
```

And my view (just the Monday `editorFor` and `timePicker`s to keep it short):

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.maandag, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.maandag, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "maandag"} })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.maandag, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-5"><b>van</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="startMa" class="form-control" style="width:280px;"/>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ma_van, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-5"><b>tot</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="endMa" class="form-control" style="width:280px;" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ma_tot, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried making an `onchange function` that sends a `parameter` but for some reason my `function` wasn't recognized. And now I don't know where to begin.

I would like to keep it all in 1 function because I want to keep the code as *DRY* as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was on the right track after al. I added `onchange="schakelAanUit(this)"` to every EditorFor and made some changes to the function.

script:

```
function schakelAanUit(a) {
            var selected = a.id;
            console.log(selected);
            //maak een variabel van de timepicker
            var maStartTimePicker = $('#startMa').data("kendoTimePicker");
            var maEndTimePicker = $('#endMa').data("kendoTimePicker");

            var diStartTimePicker = $('#startDi').data("kendoTimePicker");
            var diEndTimePicker = $('#endDi').data("kendoTimePicker");

            var woStartTimePicker = $('#startWo').data("kendoTimePicker");
            var woEndTimePicker = $('#endWo').data("kendoTimePicker");

            var doStartTimePicker = $('#startDo').data("kendoTimePicker");
            var doEndTimePicker = $('#endDo').data("kendoTimePicker");

            var vrStartTimePicker = $('#startVr').data("kendoTimePicker");
            var vrEndTimePicker = $('#endVr').data("kendoTimePicker");

            var zaStartTimePicker = $('#startZa').data("kendoTimePicker");
            var zaEndTimePicker = $('#endZa').data("kendoTimePicker");

            var zoStartTimePicker = $('#startZo').data("kendoTimePicker");
            var zoEndTimePicker = $('#endZo').data("kendoTimePicker");

            if (a.value == "false" || a.value == "Afwezig") {  //Ga door als de geselecteerde waarde "false" of "Afwezig".
                switch (selected) { //Schakel de corresponderende velden uit
                    case 'maandag':
                        maStartTimePicker.enable(false);
                        maEndTimePicker.enable(false);
                        break;
                    case 'dinsdag':
                        diStartTimePicker.enable(false);
                        diEndTimePicker.enable(false);
                        break;
                    case 'woensdag':
                        woStartTimePicker.enable(false);
                        woEndTimePicker.enable(false);
                        break;
                    case 'donderdag':
                        doStartTimePicker.enable(false);
                        doEndTimePicker.enable(false);
                        break;
                    case 'vrijdag':
                        vrStartTimePicker.enable(false);
                        vrEndTimePicker.enable(false);
                        break;
                    case 'zaterdag':
                        zaStartTimePicker.enable(false);
                        zaEndTimePicker.enable(false);
                        break;
                    case 'zondag':
                        zoStartTimePicker.enable(false);
                        zoEndTimePicker.enable(false);
                        break;
                }
            } else if(a.value == "true" || a.value == "Aanwezig") { //Ga door als de geselecteerde waarde "true" of "Aanwezig is"
                switch (selected) { //Schakel de corresponderende velden uit
                    case 'maandag':
                        maStartTimePicker.enable(true);
                        maEndTimePicker.enable(true);
                        break;
                    case 'dinsdag':
                        diStartTimePicker.enable(true);
                        diEndTimePicker.enable(true);
                        break;
                    case 'woensdag':
                        woStartTimePicker.enable(true);
                        woEndTimePicker.enable(true);
                        break;
                    case 'donderdag':
                        doStartTimePicker.enable(true);
                        doEndTimePicker.enable(true);
                        break;
                    case 'vrijdag':
                        vrStartTimePicker.enable(true);
                        vrEndTimePicker.enable(true);
                        break;
                    case 'zaterdag':
                        zaStartTimePicker.enable(true);
                        zaEndTimePicker.enable(true);
                        break;
                    case 'zondag':
                        zoStartTimePicker.enable(true);
                        zoEndTimePicker.enable(true);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

view:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.maandag, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.maandag, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "maandag", onchange="schakelAanUit(this)" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.maandag, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-5"><b>van</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="startMa" class="form-control" style="width:280px;"/>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ma_van, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-5"><b>tot</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="endMa" class="form-control" style="width:280px;" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ma_tot, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```